# Approximation of a monotone function by continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory, approximation-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}$. (*i.e.*, a locally finite Borel measure)

Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\gamma : I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a **monotone** function that is Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\mu$:
$$\int_I \gamma(x) \mathrm{d}\mu (x) < \infty.$$

I would like a simple argument to prove that there exists a sequence $(\gamma_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of **continuous and monotone** functions $\gamma_n : I \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$\int_I \gamma_n(x) \mathrm{d}\mu (x) < \infty$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_I | \gamma(x) - \gamma_n (x)| \mathrm{d}\mu (x) =0.$$

I have thought I could use the [Lusin theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/31380), but it would require to adapt its statement and proof to show the approximating functions are monotone.
Besides, my hypotheses are much simpler ($\mathbb{R}$, no compacity of the support of approximating functions). So maybe a weaker theorem could give the answer? I am interested by any reference to such theorem.

N.B.: a proof of this is very common if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, but here there is no absolute continuity assumption on $\mu$.

Comment: I don't quite get it. For the  Lebesgue measure what would be an example of such a function $\gamma$ (besides the identically equal to zero)?

Comment: The integrals should be over $I,$ not $\mathbb R.$

Comment: You are right. Correction done.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your version of Lusin's theorem can be used to give a short proof of the result, since we need some control over the continuous functions we get. Here's a solution, using a slightly weaker version of Lusin's theorem, and constructing the continuous functions more explicitly.

Let's assume $\gamma$ is non-decreasing (otherwise, work with $-\gamma$). First let's consider $I$ a compact interval of the form $I=[a,b]$, and let's deal with the general case later.

Let $\epsilon>0$. By Lusin's theorem, there exists a subset $A\subseteq I$ of measure $\geq \mu(I)-\epsilon$ such that $\gamma|_A$ (the restriction of $\gamma$ to $A$) is continuous. (This is the slightly weaker form of Lusin's theorem than the one you linked to). Moreover, by regularity of $\mu$, we can assume $A$ is closed.

We can also assume that $b\in A$: If this is not the case, then since $A$ is closed, $A\cup\{b\}$ is also closed and $\gamma|_{A\cup\{b\}}$ is continuous. Similarly, we can assume $a\in A$.

Now we will extend $\gamma|_A$ to a continuous, non-decreasing function on $I$. The complement $O=I\setminus A$ of $A$ is an open set, so it can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals $O=\bigcup_n (a_n,b_n)$. Note that $a_n,b_n\in A$ for all $n$.

Define $g=\gamma$ on $A$, and on each set $(a_n,b_n)$, define $g(x)=\gamma(a_n)+\frac{x-a_n}{b_n-a_n}(\gamma(b_n)-\gamma(a_n))$. Let's show that $g$ has the desired properties:

> **1. $g$ is monotone**

Suppose $x<y$ in $I$. We have some cases:

1.1. $x,y\in A$.

Then $g(x)=\gamma(x)<\gamma(y)=g(y)$.

1.2. $x\in A$, $y\not\in A$.

In this case, $y$ is in some set of the form $(a_n,b_n)$, and we must have $x\leq a_n$, so
$$g(x)=\gamma(x)\leq\gamma(a_n)\leq g(y)$$

1.3. $x\not\in A$, $y\in A$.

This is similar to 1.2.

1.4. $x,y\not\in A$.

Then $x\in (a_n,b_n)$ and $y\in(a_m,b_m)$ for certain $n,m$. If $n=m$ then it is clear that $g(x)\leq g(y)$. If $n\neq m$, then the interval $(a_n,b_n)$ stands to the left of the interval $(a_m,b_m)$ (since they are disjoint and contain $x$ and $y$, respectively, and $x<y$), so $b_n\leq a_m$ and thus
$$g(x)\leq g(b_n)=\gamma(b_n)\leq\gamma(a_m)=g(a_m)\leq g(y).$$

> **2. $g$ is continuous.**

We leave the following result as an exercise:

> **Proposition:** Suppose $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotone and $x\in [a,b)$. Suppose that there exists a sequence $x_n\in[a,b]$ with $x_n>x$, $x_n\to x$ and $g(x_n)\to g(x)$. Then $g$ is right-continuous as $x$.

Let's use this result: Let $x\in[a,b)$, and let's find a sequence as in the proposition. If $x\not\in A$, then $x\in(a_n,b_n)$ for some $n$ and it is easy enough to find such a sequence (e.g. $x_i=x+(b_n-x)/i$). So suppose $x\in A$. We have two cases:

2.1. There is a sequence $x_n\in A$ with $x_n>x$, $x_n\to x$.

Since $\gamma|_A=g|_A$ is continuous, we immediately have $g(x_n)\to g(x)$.

2.2. There is no sequence $x_n\in A$ with $x_n>x$, $x_n\to x$.

This means that there is some open interval of the form $(x,c)$ which does not intersect $A$, i.e., $(x,c)\subseteq I\setminus A$ and thus $(x,c)\subseteq(a_n,b_n)$ for some $n$. But $x\in A$, so $x=a_n$. Now it is again easy to construct the desired sequence (say $x_i=x+(b_i-a_i)/i$).

Therefore $g$ is right-continuous. Left continuity is similar and therefore $g$ is continuous.

> **3. $\int_I|\gamma-g|d\mu$ is small.**

Both $\gamma$ and $g$ are bounded on $I$ by $\max(|\gamma(a)|,\gamma(b)|)$, and they coincide on a set of measure $\geq\mu(I)-\epsilon$, thus
$$\int_I|\gamma-g|d\mu\leq\max(|\gamma(a)|,\gamma(b)|)\epsilon$$
which is as small as necessary, by adjusting $\epsilon$.

Note that from this it follows that $\int_I|g|d\mu<\infty$.

---

The above solves the case of a compact interval $I$. If $I$ is of the form $I=[a,b)$, with $b\in(a,\infty]$, then we can write $I=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[a_n,a_{n+1}]$, where $a=a_1<a_2<\cdots$ and $a_n\to b$.

Given $\epsilon>0$, for each $n$ find a function $g_n$ on $[a_n,a_{n+1}]$, as above, which is continuous, monotone, $g_n(a_n)=\gamma(a_n)$, $g_n(a_{n+1})=\gamma(a_{n+1})$, and $\int_{[a_n,b_n]}|g_n-\gamma|d\mu<2^{-n}\epsilon$. Define $g$ on $I$ as $g|_{[a_n,a_{n+1}]}=g_n$, and we have the desired properties.

The last case is of intervals of the form $I=(a,b)$, with $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$, and it follows from the previous case with arguments similar to the ones in the paragraph above.

---

**Alternative solution:**

We can assume that $I=[a,b]$ is compact and $\gamma$ is non-decreasing and non-constant. Moreover, up to normalization, we can assume $\gamma(a)=0$ and $\gamma(b)=1$. Let's start with the usual simple functions approximating $\gamma$: For each $n$ and $1\leq i<2^n$, take $A_{n,i}=\gamma^{-1}[\frac{i-1}{2^n},\frac{i}{2^n})$, and $A_{n,2^n}=\gamma^{-1}[\frac{2^n-1}{2^n},1]$.

Since $\gamma$ is monotone, each $A_{n,i}$ is an interval (possibly degenerate). Whenever $A_{n,i}$ has nonempty interior (i.e., it is not a point), take $a_{n,i}<b_{n,i}$ with $\operatorname{int}(A_{n,i})=(a_{n,i},b_{n,i})$. Notice that $a_{n,i}=0$ for precisely one $i$, and $b_{n,i}=1$ for precisely one $i$, and $\left\{a_{n,i}\right\}\setminus\left\{0\right\}=\left\{b_{n,i}\right\}\setminus\left\{1\right\}$.

Now take a decreasing sequence $\delta_n$ converging to $0$, in such a way that $a_{n,i}+\delta_n<b_{n,i}-\delta_n$ for all $n,i$. Let $B_{n,i}=(a_{n,i}+\delta_n,b_{n,i}-\delta_n)$.

Given $n$, define $g_n:I\to[0,1]$ as follows: $g_n(a_{n,i})=\gamma(a_{n,i})$, and $g_n(b_{n,i})=\gamma(b_{n,i})$ for all $i$. If $x\in B_{n,i}$ for some $i$, set $g_n(x)=i2^{-n}$. Then extend $g_n$ arbitrarily to some continuous, monotone function on $I$.

Let's show that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $\gamma$. For convenience, for each $n$ consider the partition $\mathscr{P}_n=\left\{A_{n,i}:i\right\}$. Note that $\mathscr{P}_m$ refines $\mathscr{P}_n$ whenever $m\geq n$.

Let $x\in I$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. We have two cases:

If $x=a_{k,i}$ for some $i$, then for every $m\geq k$ there will be some $j$ with $x=a_{m,j}$. This happens because $\mathscr{P}_m$ refines $\mathscr{P}_k$. So in this case we have $g_m(x)=\gamma(x)$ for all $m\geq k$. The same happens if $x=b_{k,i}$ for some $i$.

Now suppose $x$ is not any of the $a_{k,i}$ nor any of the $b_{k,i}$. Choose $i$ for which $x\in A_{k,i}$. Then $x$ lies in the interior of $A_{k,i}$, i.e., $x\in(a_{k,i},b_{k,i})$. Choose $N>k$ large enough such that $a_{k,i}+\delta_N<x<b_{k,i}-\delta_N$.

Now let's show that for any $m\geq N$, we have $|g_m(x)-\gamma(x)|\leq 2^{1-k}$. Again, we have some cases:

If $x$ is of the form $a_{m,j}$ or $b_{m,j}$ then $g_m(x)=\gamma(x)$, and we are done. So suppose $x$ is not of the form $a_{m,j}$ nor $b_{m,j}$. Again, there will be some $j$ for which $x\in\operatorname{int}(A_{m,j})=(a_{m,j},b_{m,j})$.

Take $p$ for which $b_{m,p}=b_{k,i}$. Again, since $\mathscr{P}_m$ refines $\mathscr{P}_k$, we have $A_{m,p}\subset A_{k,i}$, and the definition (and nonemptyness) of these sets garantees that $p2^{-m}\leq (i+1)2^{-k}$. Indeed, given $y\in A_{m,p}$, we have
$$(p-1)2^{-m}\leq\gamma(y)\leq p2^{-m}\qquad\text{and}\qquad (i-1)2^{-k}\leq\gamma(y)\leq i2^{-k}$$
so
$$p2^{-m}\leq\gamma(y)+2^{-m}\leq\gamma(y)+2^{-k}\leq (i+1)2^{-k}.$$

By our choice of $\delta$, we have $x<b_{n,i}-\delta_N\leq b_{m,p}-\delta_m$, so we can find some $y\in B_{m,p}$ with $x\leq y$. Since $g_m$ is monotone,
$$g_m(x)\leq g_m(y)=p2^{-m}\leq (i+1)2^{-k}$$

With the same kind of reasoning (now working with the $a_{m,j}$), we can prove that
$$(i-1)2^{-k}\leq g_m(x)$$
so we have
$$(i-1)2^{-k}\leq g_m(x)\leq(i+1)2^{-k}$$
and also, now by definition of $A_{k,i}$,
$$(i-1)2^{-k}\leq \gamma(x)\leq i2^{-k}\leq (i+1)2^{-k}$$
so $|g_m(x)-\gamma(x)|\leq 2^{1-k}$, as we wanted.

Therefore $g_m\to \gamma$ pointwise (everywhere!), and dominated convergence implies $\int g_m\to\int\gamma$. We did not assume anything about the measure (just that it was finite on $I$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which looks great.
Only a small flaw:
– The Lusin theorem does say $\gamma$ is continuous on $A$, but $\gamma_{\mid A}$ is continuous.
– Similarly, one should say $\gamma_{\mid A \cup \{b\}}$ is continuous rather than $\gamma$ is continuous on  $A \cup \{b\}$.

Comment: @PhilippeCuvillier You are right, and I corrected it accordingly. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: I am remembering that monotone functions are Baire functions. For monotone functions, pointwise convergence would be enough to prove the L1 convergence on compact sets (independently of the measure $\mu$!)
Could we adapt your construction to get an explicit construction of continuous functions that converge pointwise to $\gamma$?

Comment: @PhilippeCuvillier I had written this yesterday but for some reason it didn't upload... Anyway, I'm not sure if we can adapt the original solution to obtain pointwise convergence, but another argument (with very similar ideas) does give us pointwise convergence (everywhere, which I didn't expect when I started thinking about it!!). I added the details as an "Alternative Solution".

Comment: It appears to me that in the alternate solution the function g_m is not monotone. Its value in B_n,i exceeds its value at b_n,i. Am I reading the definition wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

@Luiz Cordeiro: thanks for your answer.

I may have an alternative answer for the case $I = [a, b]$, with is reminiscent of the good old Riemann integration and does not use Lusin theorem.
Assume $\gamma(a) \neq \gamma (b)$ (else, there is nothing to do).

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Define $\tilde\epsilon := \epsilon / |\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)|$.
Since $\mu$ is locally finite, $\mu$ must have a finite number of atoms whose mass is $\geq \tilde\epsilon$. Therefore, there exists a finite partition $(A_n)_{n=1}^N$ of $I$ (with $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$) such that

- for all $n \leq N$, $\mu (\mathring{A}_n) \leq \tilde\epsilon$,
- $A_n := [x_n, x_{n+1})$ for all $n < N$, and $A_N := [x_N, x_{N+1}]$,
- $a = x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_N < x_{N+1} = b$.

(the idea is to choose some of the $(a_n)$ as those big atoms)

Define $f$ piecewise with
$$\forall x \in A_n, \qquad f(x) := \gamma(x_{n}) + (\gamma(x_{n+1}) - \gamma(x_n)) \frac{x-x_n}{x_{n+1}-x_n}.$$

Since $\gamma$ is monotone,

- $\forall x \in A_n, \quad |f(x)-\gamma(x)| \leq |\gamma(x_{n+1})-\gamma(x_n)|,$
- $\sum_{n=1}^N  |\gamma(x_{n+1})-\gamma(x_n)| = |\gamma(b)-\gamma(a)|,$
- $f$ is continuous, monotone and coincides with $\gamma$ on the boundaries of all $A_n$.

In addition,
$$\int_I |\gamma-f| \mathrm{d}\mu = \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{A_n} |\gamma-f| \mathrm{d}\mu = \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{\mathring{A}_n} |\gamma-f| \mathrm{d}\mu$$
$$\leq \sum_{n=1}^N \int_{\mathring{A}_n} |\gamma(x_{n+1})-\gamma(x_n)| \mathrm{d}\mu (t)$$
$$\leq \sum_{n=1}^N  |\gamma(x_{n+1})-\gamma(x_n)| \int_{\mathring{A}_n} \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \frac{\epsilon}{|\gamma(b)-\gamma (a)|} \sum_{n=1}^N  |\gamma(x_{n+1})-\gamma(x_n)|,$$
so
$$\int_I |\gamma-f| \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \epsilon.$$

For the case $I$ is not compact, Luiz Cordeiro's argument can be used.